# kill プロセスIDが終了しません

Tags: mysql

MySQLで「kill プロセスID」を実行しましたが、正常にプロセスが終了しません。

```
mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
+-----+-----------------+-----------------+------+---------+---------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| Id  | User            | Host            | db   | Command | Time    | State                  | Info                                           |
+-----+-----------------+-----------------+------+---------+---------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|   4 | event_scheduler | localhost       | NULL | Daemon  | 1230134 | Waiting on empty queue | NULL                                           |
|  29 | root            | localhost:56181 | umls | Killed  |  951492 | executing              | SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM `UMLS`.`MRCONSO` |
| 152 | root            | localhost       | NULL | Query   |       0 | starting               | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST                          |
+-----+-----------------+-----------------+------+---------+---------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

しばらく待つしかないのでしょうか。
対処法など教えていただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: えっとデータベースファイルに矛盾を生じてもよいから MySQL プロセスを殺したいのか、ミスって超絶時間のかかる SQL 文を投げてしまったのでその SQL 文だけ止めたいのか、それ以外なのかが読者にわからないです。その辺を質問文の編集で追記してもらえると良い回答がつくかもしれないです。

Comment: 時間のかかる SQL 文を投げてしまった(SELECT文)、になります。しばらく待つとprocess listからプロセスIDは無くなると思いますが、今回は10日ほど経ってもなくならないため質問を投げさせていただきました。

Answer (score 1):

MySQLのKillコマンドはプロセスを切るするというよりも、強制終了フラグを立てておいて実行中に強制終了フラグのありなしでプロセスを終了するしないの判定をしています。

強制終了フラグのチェックタイミングはどういったQueryを実行しているかによります。
リファレンスも確認してみてください。

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/kill.html

> KILLを使用すると、そのスレッドのスレッド固有の強制終了フラグが設定されます。強制終了フラグは次の一定の間隔でしかチェックされないため、ほとんどの場合、スレッドが終了するまでにある程度時間がかかることがあります。